# How to make the keyboard upside down on top of the screen?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-softkeyboard

I'm creating a 1 on 1 poker chip counter app for my **android** begginers project.
How to make the keyboard appear upside down and on top of the screen when clicked on those EditText fields, for Player 2 to use it properly?
I've circled the problematic EditText fields in [image] picture. 
This link takes you to the whole code: https://discussions.udacity.com/t/poker-score-keeper/219350/4?u=justasd

Comment: Force user to use swiftkey instead https://blog.swiftkey.com/how-do-i-undock-the-keyboard-on-swiftkey-for-android/

Comment: @program programmer that link takes us to a Sign In, You should post it here we are not here to go through each and everyone's link and review them

Comment: @Charuක I can't post the code here because it's too long. I don't have any priviliges since I'm a new user. Could you suggest how can I post that code here?

Comment: you can't do that except if you create your own keyboard, or even Android firmware for certain device.